# Laravel MorphMany not always returning object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two related objects: UserProfile and Media.
Media is a polymorphic object with the fields:

- id
- mediable_id
- mediable_type
- user_id
- function

... and more

My UserProfile media method looks like this:

```
protected $with = ['media'];

public function media(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Media', 'mediable')
                ->whereFunction('profile')
                ->latest()->take(1);
}
```

If I understand the "$with" attribute correct, this should return the Media object everytime a UserProfile is returned?

But when I User::find(1) it returns the User with the UserProfile but no "Media" object.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $with = ['profile'];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?